# Make a <td> clickable and get the value in javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I'm trying to make a `<td>` clickable and get the value to javascript. I've got multiple `<td>` generated by my Django backend, one example:

```html
<td class="hostname"><a href="javascript:void(0)"
    onclick="clientInfo();">Client001</a></td>
```

When I click it triggers the JavaScript

```js
function clientInfo() {
  var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
  var $hostname = $row.find("hostname").text();
  alert($hostname);
}
```

but the $hostname stays empty.

The JS works with a button in a `<td>` the only thing that differs is the JS call with `onClick()`.

Comment: Please provide the HTML and JS for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Provide HTML also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the original looks like when you say it works.

But `this` in that function refers to the Window object. You can see about doing `console.log(this)`. To fix that, you can try using the event object instead:

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="hostname"><a href="javascript:void(0)"
    onclick="clientInfo(event)">Client001</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

```js
function clientInfo(e) {
  var $row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
  var $hostname = $row.find(".hostname").text();
  console.log($hostname);
}
```